# Why e.target.value reflect the latest value?

Tags: html, dom-events

I'm a beginner in HTML, just a question on input, I have html code as:

```
<input type="text" value="abc" onChange={(e) => {
         console.log(e.target.value);
     }}/>
```

I couldn't update the input value whose default is abc, fair enough, but if I type some like 'def' in the input, the console will log 'abcdef', but isn't that the input value is always default value 'abc'?

Answer (score 0):

The [`value` *property*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-value) is defined as the current value of the input, not the value of the [value attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-value) (which is available via [`getAttribute('value')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or the [`defaultValue` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-defaultvalue)).